# Ascii Encoding is ditching the £

Tags: c#, encoding, google-url-shortener

I'm using the Google Shortener and the only working example I could find (below) encodes the URL string ASCII.  The problem is that when the link contains £ the ASCII replaces it with ?.  This means that when the link is shortened and its clicked, the URL is incorrect.  I've tried lots of different encodings but the this stops the Google shorterner from working.  I either need to come up with an encoding that the shortener the Google will allow or change the code.  I'd rather do the former.  Any help?

```
public static string ShortenItBasic(string url, ref string returnedJson, ref bool succeeded, string urlShortenerId = null)
    {
        string finalURL = null;
        string post = "{\"longUrl\": \"" + url + "\"}";
        string urlShortener = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlShortenerId))
        {
            urlShortener = urlShortenerId;
        }
        else
        {
            urlShortener = ConfigKeys.GoogleShortenerAPIKey;
        }

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=" + urlShortener);
        try
        {
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentLength = post.Length;
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                byte[] postBuffer = null;

                if (ConfigKeys.IsDebugMode)
                {
                    postBuffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM437").GetBytes(post);

                    //postBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);
                }
                else
                {
                    postBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post);
                }

                requestStream.Write(postBuffer, 0, postBuffer.Length);
            }
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        string json = responseReader.ReadToEnd(); 

                        returnedJson = json;

                        finalURL = Regex.Match(json, @"""id"": ?""(?<id>.+)""").Groups["id"].Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // if Google's URL Shortener is down...
            Logging.LoggingIO.LogHelper("GoogleBitly: Issue with the shortener: <br/><br/>" + ex.Message + " Stack: " + ex.StackTrace);

            succeeded = false;

            return "There is a problem with the Google shortening service: " + ex.Message + ".  Please try another target";
        }

        succeeded = true;
        return finalURL;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A URL cannot contain the £ character, since it's not an ASCII character. Any character outside of a small subset of ASCII valid in URLs must be [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), e.g. to `%C2%A3` for a UTF-8 encoded £, or `%A3` for an ISO-8859-1 encoded £ (whichever your server prefers to receive). *URL-encode* your values when building the URL.

Comment: I'll try the percent encoding.  URLs can contain £, the very link to this article contains one.  Whether you should or not is another thing :).

Comment: Your browser may helpfully be rending `%C2%A3` as £, but the URL itself does not actually contain it. Inspect the `href` of links to this question.

Comment: Also, I should add that the server in this case is Google so I can't do anything about the encoding it receives.

Comment: Google has little to do with it. The URL you're trying to shorten must be correctly percent-encoded; if it is then encodings are no issue whether you send it to Google or elsewhere.